# How do I hide a button so that it turns see-through rather than white?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, hidden, uitoolbar

I am trying to program a view which has a list of exercises in a table view. The user can either swipe them to delete or go into edit mode and click multiple rows to delete faster (much like in mail).

At the bottom of the screen there is a finish button where the user will click when s/he has finished choosing the exercises they want in their workout. Currently I am trying to bring up the toolbar when the user enters edit mode to allow them to delete their multiple choices. When this happens the view is compressed and so the finish button raises up above the toolbar. This isn't what I want as it looks stupid to be able to finish while editing something else.

I have tried hiding the button but this leaves a white square just above the toolbar

I am not sure if I need to make the button transparent or if I am hiding it incorrectly.

How can I have the bottom button disappear completely when edit mode is entered to the extent it doesn't affect my table view and then reappear and almost 'swap' with the tool bar when editing mode is exited?

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    // Activates multiple selection
    exercisesSelectedTableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = editing;

    // Lets us know we have clicked editing - changes it to done
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing) {
        // This bit is done when someone clicks edit

        // Sets the view into editing mode
        [exercisesSelectedTableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];

        // Unhides the tool bar
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];

        // Hides the finish button
        [finishedButton setHidden:YES];
    }
    else {
         // This bit is called once someone clicks done

        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];

        // Reveals finish button 
        [finishedButton setHidden:NO];

        [super setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        [exercisesSelectedTableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this out eventually.

Using the setToolBarHidden works fine but in the XIB file I needed to check that the table view went all the way down to the bottom of the view. As it was the table view only went to the top of the finished button. Therefore when it was hidden it left the white gap I assumed was the shadow of the button.

Morale of the story: Check the XIB files carefully